# Form data not always send in Chrome when uploading file with Angular 7

Tags: angular, google-chrome

When uploading files with my Angular 7 app using angular-file, form data is not always send with Chrome (macOS). I have no problems with Firefox or Safari. Refreshing Chrome (F5) helps at least last time when this happened.

I upgraded angular-file to it's newest version but it didn't helped. I think this isn't angular-file problem, because I use Angular common's HttpRequest to do the upload.

Angular code looks like this:

```
  uploadFile(file: File, type: string): Subscription {
    const fileFormData: FormData = new FormData();
    fileFormData.append("file", file, file.name);

    const req = new HttpRequest<FormData>('PUT', '/api/v2/images/' + type, fileFormData, {
      reportProgress: true
    });

    return this.httpEmitter = this.http.request<any>(req)
      .subscribe(
        event => {
          this.appUtil.logHttpEvent(event, file);

          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.httpEmitter.unsubscribe();
            this.setImageUrl(type);
          }
        }
      );
  }

  logHttpEvent(event: any, file: File) {
        switch (event.type) {
            case HttpEventType.Sent:
                console.log(`Uploading file "${file.name}" of size ${file.size}.`);
                return;

            case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                console.log(`File "${file.name}" is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
                return;

            case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
                console.log(`File "${file.name}" upload got response header ${event.status}/${event.statusText}`);
                return;

            case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                console.log(`File "${file.name}" upload got download progress loaded ${event.loaded} bytes`);
                return;

            case HttpEventType.Response:
                console.log(`File "${file.name}" was completely uploaded!`);
                return;

            default:
                console.log(`File "${file.name}" surprising upload event: ${event.type}.`);
                return;
        }
    }
```

When upload works it prints to console:

```
main.23cb89c05a4329fb2f30.js:1 Uploading file "logo.png" of size 6631.
main.23cb89c05a4329fb2f30.js:1 File "logo.png" upload got response header 200/OK
main.23cb89c05a4329fb2f30.js:1 File "logo.png" upload got download progress loaded 1930 bytes
main.23cb89c05a4329fb2f30.js:1 File "logo.png" was completely uploaded!
```

But when it fails it prints:

```
main.23cb89c05a4329fb2f30.js:1 Uploading file "logo.png" of size 6631.
POST https://www.example.com/api/v2/images/logo 500
main.23cb89c05a4329fb2f30.js:1 File "logo.png" upload got response header 500/OK
main.23cb89c05a4329fb2f30.js:1 File "logo.png" upload got download progress loaded 205 bytes
```

When I check network tab there isn't "Form Data" section after "Request Headers" at all when upload fails. Still in request header there's content type set correctly: "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary2SRIMu3Tb4HzNjJo"

I'm using Angular's default service worker so wondering if it could cause these problems?

Comment: Any update or solution?

Comment: I haven't got this error after 1st of August. I installed new version 3rd of August in where I have upgraded lots of dependencies including Angular 7.2.12 -> 8.1.1. I'm not sure which fixed this but I'm just glad it's now working ok.

Comment: Our issue was caused by the service worker and only under Chrome Macos version 77.  The solution was to skip the use of service worker for our files uploads.

Comment: I had forgotten, but we also added ngsw-bypass=true parameter (that was introduced in Angular 8) for uploads.

Comment: put the solution into answer, it could help people

Answer (score 4):

Solution was to add ngsw-bypass -parameter (introduced in Angular 8) into url, like:

```
const req = new HttpRequest<FormData>('POST', '/api/v2/attachments/orders/' + this.order.id + '?ngsw-bypass=true', fileFormData, {
  reportProgress: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass Service Worker if you are using @angular/service-worker: 8+ by adding { headers: { 'ngsw-bypass': true } or query param ngsw-bypass=true to your request.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29629