# Chrome does not always send form data to my (self-implemented) server

Tags: java, forms, http, server

This morning I wrote a custom server in Java. Eventually, I want to use it as the backend for a react-native app, and so I was working on implementing file-uploading. I've been testing this with a simple HTML form that submits its data to my local machine. When I parse the HTTP request headers, I extract the Content-Length of the data section of the request (hereafter refered to as the "message body" of the request). Sometimes, the message body of the HTTP request contains the file name and contents, but more often than not it is empty, even if the Content-Length and Content-Type (including the form boundary) are set correctly (non-zero length, "--WebKitBoundary..." boundary). I can detect this and timeout (and no, increasing my timeout does not let me read more data), but the fact that the HTTP request seems to indicate that there should be data when none is received seems like a significant issue.

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413685/form-data-not-always-send-in-chrome-when-uploading-file-with-angular-7) seems to be exactly what I am seeing, but as of this posting it has not been answered.

This is the class I use to read data from the InputStream of the established Socket connection:

```
public class HTTPRequest {

    // full request, HTTP verb + URI, meta-data, message body
    public final String request, requestline, headers, data;

    // regex to find the length of the message body
    private static final Pattern contentlength = Pattern.compile("Content-Length\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)");


    /*
     * when an object is created it reads the entire HTTP request from the stream and sets its constant strings accordingly
     */
    public HTTPRequest(InputStream is) throws Exception {

        /*
         * get everything except the message body
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("resource") // closing the Scanner closes the stream, so suppressing the resource leak warning
        Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
        requestline = s.nextLine();
        s.useDelimiter("\r\n\r\n");
        headers = s.next();

        // get the reported length of the message body, 0 if not present
        Matcher m = contentlength.matcher(headers);
        int length = 0;
        if(m.find()) {
            length = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        }

        // if there is a message body, read it
        if(length > 0) {

            // this will contain the message bytes
            byte[] b = new byte[length];

            // number of bytes read, number of consecutive times I read 0 bytes
            int read = 0;
            int numzeros = 0;

            // read until I've read the entire message
            while(read < length) {

                // read however many bytes are available
                int numread = is.read(b, read, is.available());
                read += numread;

                if(numread == 0) {
                    numzeros++;
                }else {
                    numzeros = 0;
                }

                // timeout after not getting any data for 1 second
                if(numzeros > 100) {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }

            data = new String(b, 0, read);

        // otherwise, no message body
        }else {
            data = "";
        }

        // combine all of the parts of the request
        request = requestline + "\r\n" + headers + "\r\n\r\n" + data;
    }
}
```

and here is the HTML I've been using to upload the file:

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:54600/api/test/test/uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="name" type="text" />
<input name="upload" type="file" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
```

This is what I read from the InputStream:

```
POST /api/test/test/uploadFile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 531
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzkLQnlCjBb2a5sOP
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

which, apart from not having any message body, seems to be correct. Earlier today, I found that I usually got a message body if I uploaded a unique file each time I submitted the form (submitting the same file more than once tended not to have the message body, though it occasionally did). Now, I can't seem to get a message body at all.

Update, after writing the last paragraph, I decided to test some more in another tab. This time, I got a message body:

```
POST /api/test/test/uploadFile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54600
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1162
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryErwo4zpzcDBuyDo5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

------WebKitFormBoundaryErwo4zpzcDBuyDo5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

test_name
------WebKitFormBoundaryErwo4zpzcDBuyDo5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="hello_world.o"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

ELF [... binary data]
------WebKitFormBoundaryErwo4zpzcDBuyDo5--
```

I tested some more in this new tab, and most of the time I got the form data, but already I have seen it not send the message body two or three times. There doesn't seem to be a discernable pattern for when the form submission does not include the message body.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

The first one is the most likely to cause your problem:

**Scanner isn't a good choice here**, since it will not stop reading your InputStream at `"\r\n\r\n"`. Scanner only works well when it's the only thing reading your `InputStream`, not when you want to read it directly as well. Scanner will try to fill its internal buffer first and then search in its buffer for `\r\n\r\n`. So it will invariably read beyond that. And those bytes will not be available in the `InputStream` anymore in the second part of your function.

So you can't use `Scanner` - you need to read directly from the `InputStream` until you have seen `\r\n\r\n`; only then an you be sure that you have read the request correctly without reading any of the request body yet.

The second problem is that **using `InputStream.available()` is a brittle way to read data**. You are very much depending on networking timing and that could be off by quite a bit. If the data is coming in quickly, you are waiting to long since you do a Thread.sleep for every read. And if it doesn't come in fast enough, you may timeout too quickly.

A much more reliable way to read is this:

```
while(read < length) {
    int numread = is.read(b, read, length - read);
    if (numread < 0)
        break;
    read += numread;
}
```

then on the incoming Socket object, you set a read timeout using [`Socket.setSoTimeout` (link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) to a reasonable timeout for your purposes. I would take at least 30 seconds or a minute - you don't know what network is between the client and your server.

As a toy project it's of course fun to write your own HTTP server. However, I wouldn't advise it for production code. The HTTP protocol is pretty complex nowadays and there are plenty of good open source HTTP server that you can use in your application directly (Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow and others all allow you to do that) - you don't need to deploy a WAR file or anything like that. You *can* use the servlet API, but if you want to use highly scalable asynchronous HTTP for example, you could have a look at Netty.